# Open zipped html/javascript/css in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

I have a webservice which provides some zipped html files (index + directory with all required resources).

On client side, I would like to extract this zipped file, then open the say index.html file directly in the browser.

I managed to unzip all files but I don't know how I am suppose to save them somewhere so relative links within the files work. I don't even know if it is possible to save these files in a /tmp directory.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing in Angular and I can't seem to settle on a decent solve for this.

Comment: @katyusha no I didn't find a good solution on client side. I fixed it on server side (the server unzip the content and serves the files).